# R mutate() working with paste0()

Tags: r, dplyr

I just observed a very weird behaviour that I cannot explain when comparing `paste0` and `paste` applied with `mutate`:

```
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% ungroup() %>% mutate(`newcol ss` = paste0(as.character(wt), as.character(drat), collapse=";"))
```

The output of the above piece of code using `paste0` is as follows:

[image]

```
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% ungroup() %>% mutate(`newcol ss` = paste(as.character(wt), as.character(drat)))
```

The output of the `paste()` function is as follows:
[image]

Basically mutate works well with `paste` (combine two column by row) while the `paste0` combines all columns and rows in a single cell.

Comment: Why are you bothering with such a complex piece of code? Couldn't you just use `mtcars$ss <- paste0(mtcars$wt, mtcars$drat, sep = " ")`

Comment: Also paste0 has a collapse specified, and paste doesn't... That's why https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.3/topics/paste

Comment: If you do ```mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% ungroup() %>% mutate(`newcol ss` = paste(as.character(wt), as.character(drat), collapse = ";"))```, it combines the entire ```wt``` and ```drat``` columns as well. So it's not a difference between ```paste``` and ```paste0```.

Comment: @griffinevo sorry for the complex code, just try to reproduce the same problem I came across in a project. But here my question is why all columns are combined in the first scenario.

Comment: The collapse argument - as noted in my answer - is nor equal in your two scenarios. That is causing the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `collapse` (and add a `" "` inside the `paste0` function) to match the result when you used `paste`:

```
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% ungroup() %>% mutate(`newcol ss` = paste0(as.character(wt), " ", as.character(drat)))
```

You can produce your weird result using `paste` as well:

```
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% ungroup() %>% mutate(`newcol ss` = paste(as.character(wt), as.character(drat), collapse = ";"))

> mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% ungroup() %>% mutate(`newcol ss` = paste(as.character(wt), as.character(drat), collapse = ";"))
# A tibble: 32 x 13
     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb ss           `newcol ss`                                                         
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>        <chr>                                                               
 1  21.0    6.  160.  110.  3.90  2.62  16.5    0.    1.    4.    4. "2.623.9 "   2.62 3.9;2.875 3.9;2.32 3.85;3.215 3.08;3.44 3.15;3.46 2.76;3.57 3.~
 2  21.0    6.  160.  110.  3.90  2.88  17.0    0.    1.    4.    4. "2.8753.9 "  2.62 3.9;2.875 3.9;2.32 3.85;3.215 3.08;3.44 3.15;3.46 2.76;3.57 3.~
 3  22.8    4.  108.   93.  3.85  2.32  18.6    1.    1.    4.    1. "2.323.85 "  2.62 3.9;2.875 3.9;2.32 3.85;3.215 3.08;3.44 3.15;3.46 2.76;3.57 3.~
 4  21.4    6.  258.  110.  3.08  3.22  19.4    1.    0.    3.    1. "3.2153.08 " 2.62 3.9;2.875 3.9;2.32 3.85;3.215 3.08;3.44 3.15;3.46 2.76;3.57 3.~
 5  18.7    8.  360.  175.  3.15  3.44  17.0    0.    0.    3.    2. "3.443.15 "  2.62 3.9;2.875 3.9;2.32 3.85;3.215 3.08;3.44 3.15;3.46 2.76;3.57 3.~
 6  18.1    6.  225.  105.  2.76  3.46  20.2    1.    0.    3.    1. "3.462.76 "  2.62 3.9;2.875 3.9;2.32 3.85;3.215 3.08;3.44 3.15;3.46 2.76;3.57 3.~
 7  14.3    8.  360.  245.  3.21  3.57  15.8    0.    0.    3.    4. "3.573.21 "  2.62 3.9;2.875 3.9;2.32 3.85;3.215 3.08;3.44 3.15;3.46 2.76;3.57 3.~
 8  24.4    4.  147.   62.  3.69  3.19  20.0    1.    0.    4.    2. "3.193.69 "  2.62 3.9;2.875 3.9;2.32 3.85;3.215 3.08;3.44 3.15;3.46 2.76;3.57 3.~
 9  22.8    4.  141.   95.  3.92  3.15  22.9    1.    0.    4.    2. "3.153.92 "  2.62 3.9;2.875 3.9;2.32 3.85;3.215 3.08;3.44 3.15;3.46 2.76;3.57 3.~
10  19.2    6.  168.  123.  3.92  3.44  18.3    1.    0.    4.    4. "3.443.92 "  2.62 3.9;2.875 3.9;2.32 3.85;3.215 3.08;3.44 3.15;3.46 2.76;3.57 3.~
# ... with 22 more rows
```

Personally I'd use less complex code:

```
mtcars$ss <- paste0(mtcars$wt, " ", mtcars$drat)
```

Answer (score 0):

`collapse = ", "`  is the cause of the problem.

Try putting `collapse` in `paste`, same result will be obtained, except, space will be added between values of two columns.

It is not the differences in `paste` and `paste0` which gave difference in results.

Try understanding usage of `paste` and `paste0` and usage of `collapse`.

[[Also as griffinevo and Kim have mentioned in the comments above, stick with simpler code. ]]